# Exporting a query result into a text file using vba-MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Table in MS Access 2010 and I want to export the result of a query into a text file( the user specified a path and this Textfile should be saved in this Path)

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT Name FROM MyTable
```

and I want to have each name in a seprate row in a text file. How can I do that in VBA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case the most straightforward approach would be something like this:

```
Sub ExportToText()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Open "C:\__tmp\names.txt" For Output As #1
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Name] FROM MyTable", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Print #1, rst!Name
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You do it with DoCmd.TransferText method. Like:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim,"mySpecification","myView","C:\DATA\myfile.csv",True
```

First, you do it once manually, and save the specification (where you decide which columns to export, types, etc.).

MyView is a view you create as "SELECT Name FROM myTable"