# MS-Access flat file export error

Tags: ms-access

When I export an query result to a csv format flat file in ms access, the text fields are enclosed in quotes. Is it possible to export the text fields values without quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

During the export process flow you will have the option to select your own custom formatting and layout.  Select this check box and then you will have the opportunity to select whatever delimiter you see fit.  [See this article for further information.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-how-can-i-export-my-data-in-comma/b2f71f0d-cf2e-4e1e-b1e2-e86d84588809?auth=1)

[Here is also an example of how you can write it to a file manually using VBA.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272945/exporting-a-query-result-into-a-text-file-using-vba-ms-access)

Enjoy!

Comment: So I can save this specification and use it in the code I write to export the queries isn't it?

Comment: Yes if you are using VBA to automate the export you can also specify a delimiter.

Comment: Technically if you are doing this from VBA you will want to use a data reader and write the fields to file yourself, that way you can specify any delimiter you want.

Comment: I was using the docmd command to transfer the data to a flat file in access

Comment: [DoCmd.TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) method allows a specification as an optional argument.